# Starting with translations: leicht bekloppt wird

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Having studied a bit of German I am starting with translation. In a book called 'Männer sind wie Schokolade', first chapter, it can be found:

> Wie lange kann man wohl in einer Werbeagentur arbeiten, ohne daß man
>   leicht bekloppt wird?

I would translate it as:

> How long can you work in an advertising agency without becoming easily
>   crazy?

I apologize if it is too bad.

I am not sure how to translate "leicht bekloppt wird", because *leicht wird* und *leicht bekloppt* have different meanings. Would you help me?

Comment: Please ask about a specific part that you are unsure about, otherwise the question is likely to be closed for being a proofreading request.

Comment: *Leicht bekloppt* means *slightly silly*.

Comment: @Janka More *slightly crazy*, IMHO.

Comment: Could you pick a different title that outlines tge actual issue, please? Any question related to the meaning of a phrase could be a "translation" problem.

Comment: All concerns from your translation attempt appear to come from issues with the English language. Please [edit] your post to specifically say what you did not understand on the German side and also do edit your question title to make it related to your question. After you had done so your question will enter a reopen queue where the community may vote for reopening.

Comment: Thank you for the edit... at least the title does now say what we are asked here. I can see that you know what *bekloppt* means so I am sure you can find the English term that fits here better than we do (it would be off topic for us anyway). I can only guess from your translation that you further are in doubt about what *leicht* refers to, i.e. whether it is *leicht werden* or *leicht bekloppt*. To get this answered I will reopen your question for now, but it may be better you also edit that concern into the question so that people can quickly find the issue that is being dealt with here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that you are reading a book that was printed before the orthography reform of 1996. The correct writing of *»daß«* is now: *»dass«*.

---

I think this part is easy, you already translated it correctly:

> Wie lange kann man wohl in einer Werbeagentur arbeiten, ohne daß man bekloppt wird?
>   How long can you work in an advertising agency without becoming bonkers?

(I think *bonkers* fits better for *bekloppt* than *crazy* because *bekloppt* is a slang word.)

The word *»leicht«* in your sentence modifies the word *»bekloppt«* in this manner:

- bekloppt = chokoo, bonkers
- leicht bekloppt = slightly chokoo, slightly bonkers

You can use it also with other adjectives:

> Der Braten schmeckt leicht angebrannt.
>   The roast tastes slightly burnt. = It tastes burnt, but only a little bit.